# AJAX "post" Issue when posting html-elements

Tags: c#, html, ajax

I'm using AJAX to post the content of a `div` to my C# mvc-controller.
The AJAX post looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/SaveContent',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        model: modelDataJson,
        activeId: activeId,
        contentToUpdate: $("div#" + activeId).html()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Content hits controller. Id: " + activeId);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I'm using a WYSIWYG editor which is a div with the id: `activeId`.
So what I'm trying to post is this line: `contentToUpdate: $("div#" + activeId).html()` 
Which is this div below:

```
<div id="WelcomeText" data-photo="15" class="click2edit" style="display: block;">
    som content here
</div>
```

If I post this above my c#-controller-method gets hit and everything works.

But if I post this below, the `error: function () { alert("error");}` gets hit:

```
<div id="WelcomeText" data-photo="15" class="click2edit" style="display: block;">
    <p>som content here</p>
</div>
```

So my question is: Why doesn't the post work when including HTML? What am I missing out, seems like `contentToUpdate: $("div#" + activeId).html()` is not including the child-elements?

Comment: ASP.NET at one point had an anti-XSS filter that would block requests containing things looking like HTML. You're not running into something like that, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default MVC will reject posted values that contain HTML when binding the model on the basis that it's potentially dangerous. In your first post the value is

```
som content here
```

but in the second it's

```
<p>som content here</p>
```

The second one is detected as HTML and rejected.

To allow the HTML content you can add the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to the relevant property in your model.

For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
}
```

More info on the `AllowHtml` attribute can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

**Edit**

Based on the following from the comments:

> My controller-post-method looks like this `public void SaveContent(string model, string activeId, string contentToUpdate){}`

If that's the case then the above won't work as you don't have a model on which to apply the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

You have a couple of options:
Firstly, you could create a model and add the attribute to that then change your action method to take the new model:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string Model {get; set;}
    public string ActiveId {get; set;}
    [AllowHtml]
    public string ContentToUpdate {get; set;}
}

public void SaveContent(SomeModel model)
{
    //access model.Model, model.ActiveId and model.ContentToUpdate here
}
```

Alternatively you could keep the action method as-is and decorate the action method with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void SaveContent(string model, string activeId, string contentToUpdate)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

This will prevent validation on *all* of the parameters being sent to that action method so you should validate `model` and `activeId` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to [AllowHtml] on my property, but then my saveFile-button witch triggers the ajax stops working. What can be the issue?

Comment: @user3228992 - which version of MVC are you using? Also, do you accept a FormCollection on your controller method?

Comment: I'm using MVC "5.1". Why do I need a FormCollection? My controller-post-method looks like this `public void SaveContent(string model, string activeId, string contentToUpdate){}`. Thanks

Comment: @user3228992 - see my update. The question about FormCollection was a guess because the `AllowHtml` attribute wouldn't work if your method was like `public void SaveContent(FormCollection values){}`. You don't need to use `FormCollection` (and I don't think you _should_ either).

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I tried the fast `[ValidateInput(false)]` solution and it works perfect! I will look in to your other solution ass well!